# if $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, for $y \in \mathcal{A}$ show that $\mathcal{A}_y=\{y \cap A|A\in \mathcal{A}\}$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, for $y \in \mathcal{A}$ show that 
$$\mathcal{A}_y=\{y \cap A|A\in \mathcal{A}\}$$
 is also a $\sigma$-algebra.

So far I have shown that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}_y $:-

if $y=\emptyset$ then $y \cap A =\emptyset \cap A=\emptyset \space \space\forall A \in \mathcal{A}$ so $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}_y$

else if $y \neq \emptyset$ then we have $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, so for $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$ we have $y \cap \emptyset = \emptyset \in \mathcal{A}_y$.

But i am stuck with the last two parts:

1) if $x \in \mathcal{A}_y$ then $x^c \in \mathcal{A}_y$

2) if $E_n \in \mathcal{A}_y \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \in \mathcal{A}_y$.

What I try to do in both cases is use the fact that $\mathcal{A}_y \subset \mathcal{A}$ but the intersection in the definition of $\mathcal{A}_y$ gets me in both cases.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This proof is a result of trying to probe that a sub measure space is a measure space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1): we have to consider the complement **in $y$**. If $S\in\mathcal A_y$, then $S=y\cap A$ for some $A\in\mathcal A$. We thus have 
$y\setminus S=y\cap (X\setminus y\cup X\setminus A)=y\cap (X\setminus A)$. Since $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $X\setminus A$ belongs to $\mathcal A$ hence $y\setminus S$ belongs to $\mathcal A_y$.

For 2): if $E_n\in \mathcal A_y$, then $E_n=y\cap A_n$, with $A_n\in\mathcal A$. Since $\bigcup_n E_n=\bigcup_n(y\cap A_n)=y\cap \underbrace{\bigcup_n E_n}_{\in\mathcal A}$, we are done.

Comment: I just have one question, why is $(X\setminus y\cup X\setminus A) = (X \setminus A)$?

Comment: You missed the intersection by $y$ (in general we may have $A\cap B=A\cap C$ even if $B\neq C$).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see now, $y \cap (X \setminus y) = \emptyset$ so that's why you get $y \cap (X \setminus A)$ because intersection is distributive?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$